# Intern3.1.1 /Chrome 76 /selenium3..5.3- Command#switchToFrame failing

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, intern

all my intern.js 3.1.1 scripts are failing at `Command#switchToFrame` every time

I have upgraded to chrome 76
chromedriver.exe 76.0.3809.25
selenium 3.5.3

It was workinging till 
chrome 75 
selenium 3.4

tried using chromedriver version 76.0.3809.68

```
Error resolving: Command#switchToFrame (6ms) <>

SUITE ERROR
Error: [POST http://localhost:60891/wd/hub/session/6be57f902ac4bff9d5a29acba9c6cca2/frame / {}] invalid argument: missing 'id'
```

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format your question, especially the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chromedriver 76 supports W3C style WebDriver commands by default, but Intern 3.3.1 does not. You could try disabling W3C mode in chromedriver by passing a `w3c` capability of `false` in the environment specifier:

```
{
  "environments": [
    {
      "browser": "chrome",
      "w3c": "false"
    }
  ]
}
```